# How can I encode/decode my option list into a number

Tags: python, algorithm

I use the following example to illustrate my question: suppose now I have four parameters in my model:

```
  param1: 'a'  
  param2: 'ab'
  param3: 'abc'
  param4: 'abcd'
```

For each parameters it have a limited number of options to select. Take `param1` for example, it can choose one from the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.  Now what I am going to do is to generate a number that represents the combined options from `param1` to `param4`. One simple idea is to get the index of the selected option in each parameter setting first, and after that we multiple it with a weighting factor, and each parameter is given a different weighting factor. I show the following codes to demonstrate it:

```
   id_num = 0 
   para1_index = para1_option_list.index(para1_sel)
   para2_index = para2_option_list.index(para2_sel)
   para3_index = para3_option_list.index(para3_sel)
   para4_index = para4_option_list.index(para4_sel)
   id_num = para1_index+para2_index*10+para3_index*100+para4_index*1000
```

By doing so, for the selected parameters for my model, I have a unique number to represent it. However, I am not sure it is a elegant solution. Any ideas on improvement? Thanks.

The question comes from the project I am working on now, where I use different machine learning algorithm to generate models. And I want to use one ID number to represent different trained models.

Comment: Your list size has a maximum or it can be anything?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya The list size is assumed to be changeable, but definitely we can predict a maximum value for the list size.

Answer (score 0):

How is your binary?

```
construct a number using binary:
    For each parameter p:
        if it has o options in total then it can be represented by b binary bits
        where b = ceil(log2(o))
        
        reserve the next b-bit  field for the binary representation of the 
        option of parameter p

The final number is unique to one specific combination of parameters.
```

When coding, separate Python enumerations could be used for each parameters set of options and would provide integer representations for bit-packing above.